# How to add a context menu item to the toolbar?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have several projects in my solution.  I'd like to debug a standalone project that is not the active project.  So, I right click on it, select `Debug/Start New Instance` and it runs.

Is there a way to place this Debug/Start New instance on the toolbar somehow?  I don't see anything in the `Customize...` screen to be able to add a context menu to the toolbar.

[image]

Comment: I doubt what you are asking can be done. The problem is what you just mentioned. It's a context menu item and hence it requires the context (selection of a project) to run.

Comment: @LukkhaCoder: That's not the problem. One can add context menu items to the menu bar and have them work. For instance, `Set as StartUp Project` sets whichever Project is highlighted in the Solution Explorer as the startup project. The real problem is that a) `Start new instance` simply can't be found in any of the categories when adding a menu command (at least, not the ones I've looked in), *even when adding an item to a context menu*; and b) you can't add existing menus, only create new ones and add items.

Answer (score 1):

The command name is **ClassViewContextMenus.ClassViewProject.Debug.Startnewinstance**. I'm not sure you can add it directly to the toolbar, but you can call it from a macro and add the macro to the toolbar. Or just assign a keyboard shortcut to it.